# "- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didExitRegion:(KTKRegion *)region" getting called after every 1-2 minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, background-process, ibeacon

I am using Kontakt.io SDK for iBeacon detection.

When I entered in iBeacon region below function get called

```
- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didEnterRegion:(KTKRegion *)region;
```

and here I get region identifier (beacon UUID), but the problem is without any movement below method get called after every 1 or 2 minutes.

```
- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didExitRegion:(KTKRegion *)region;
```

And because of "didExitRegion" get called, in the next movement "didEnterRegion" get called, so I am getting repeated notification for the same region. All these functions are implemented in Appdelegate.m file. "startMonitoringBeacons" is  called in

`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

Device OS:- 9.2.1, let me know if more details required and
please let me know how can I resolved this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just ignore the notifications if you are already in that region (by not clearing the current region in `didExitRegion:`)?

Comment: If I ignore that, then how will I know if entered in the same region after 1-2 hrs. Then that time I will not get any notification for that region.

Comment: I guess you are recording the current region in an instance variable?  If so just don't clear it.  Perhaps keep a `BOOL inRegion` flag and set that to `YES` or `NO` when you get these notifications and only change your copy of the region information if it's different.

Comment: But what if the same person comes in the same region without going in another region ?